# How EF should be used in a scaled application?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, scalability, entity-framework-migrations

We are developing a SaaS application which should be scalable to several servers in the future.
Furthermore there are some additional applications accessing the same database.

Currently we are using the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer to migrate the db to the latest version in all of the applications.
Since we do x-copy-like deploys we would like that the first request migrates the database.
The backend application should display a wait-for-migration-message.

One option would be to disable the initializer and initialize the database explicitely during the first request from the backend application. The disadvantage here is, that we can not simply assure the first request is from backend application. So until the first user requests the backend app (and so triggering the migration), all the users requesting the public app will get errors.

Are there other options? 
How should I handle the case where two applications running in different app domains executes the same migration in parallel?

Thanks for any hints, ideas or tips in advance!

Comment: It's a shame that these apps aren't talking to an interim web (or other) service, as when the service started the database would be migrated and you wouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: You'd think that this was nailed down for Azure given its distributed nature, wouldn't you?

Comment: This is why I believe that fundamentally SQL can't scale. The problem isn't Entity Framework's fault. The same problems exist even without EF, just straight ADO.NET. You will have downtime and you need to bring down the webservers gracefully. X-Copy just doesn't cut it. I suggest you use the AppOffline.htm file to bring all the hosts down. Run your upgrade, bring all your hosts back up with the new version.

Comment: I wrote here a few words: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707122/208922

Comment: @Moo-Juice You are right of course. We are working on a REST API for database layer

Comment: @Moo-Juice ..., but in the meanwhile we have to arrange with our current layer :)

Comment: What did you do in the end? facing similar problem.